# What is the purpose of carrying a flight ticket receipt on paper?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tickets

I just booked a flight ticket on my next trip via *DeNA travel*, a Japan-based travel agency. In a confirmation email, the following note is written:

> In some countries, you might get asked to submit an airline ticket receipt in a printed format, not on the screen of your smartphone or tablet. In order to get through the immigration smoothly, please print and carry it during your travel.
>
> These countries include Philippines, India, Indonesia, Vietnam, Bangladesh, Iran, and some regions in China, etc...

However, I don't think most people carry it in this highly technologically advanced age. Well, you might like to carry it in case your smartphone's battery run out, but most people don't, I assume.

So what is the purpose that some countries like to see your ticket receipt in a printed format, which doesn't function at all to avoid a potential fraud? Would you get denied to the entry without it?

Comment: I agree that this does little or nothing to avoid fraud. Governments, rules and regulations are very often quite slow to adapt to new technology. Also, many countries have senseless red-tape that there is little or no logic to. Also, this question is broad. It's better if you focus on a specific country.

Comment: @Fiksdal If it is broad I like to restrict it to the countries mentioned (Philippines, India, etc...). Is it still broad enough?

Comment: Six countries, plus an unspecified number of regions in a seventh, plus "etc.", which could include every other country on the planet. That's no restriction at all. Then, there are three questions about each (probability of being denied entry, getting home if denied entry, and the unanswerable "why?"). This is far, far too broad.

Comment: Blaszard: I agree with @DavidRicherby

Comment: As a westerner, I always carry a print ticket, even if I have an electronic version (well, 'you never know'). Your assumption that 'most people don't carry' needs some sources.

Comment: @audionuma Why do Westerners, not just you, carry a printed ticket?

Comment: The 'westerner' mention was meant to mean having a laptop, mobile phone, easy internet access, things like that ... And taking into account that things might be different depending on your local culture.

Comment: Why WOULDNT you carry a printed ticket? It takes up no space, and almost no effort, lets say you loose or break your "device"...

Comment: So since the original question seems too board to fit in this site, I changed it to ask about the purpose of carrying a printed ticket. It was already answered, though.

Comment: Also something to note, some barcode scanners (Laser mostly) are incapable of reading an on-screen barcode.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft Because it is an insanely difficult task for me. I'm not kidding, I don't have a printer and the last time I printed a PDF document (not an airline ticket) it took me 4 hours to just print it...

Comment: ok, wow.... but you are ok with a "Smartphone"?! - anyway I would NEVER travel without 2x paper copies of all my documents - its called "to be sure" :-) - Happy travels!

Comment: I'm going to say the in nearly, or possible, all cases, the answer to the question as originally asked is **no**.

Keep in mind, a 'Paper Ticket' is a very specific thing.  The email from the travel agency is somewhat misleading since the *passenger cannot print a Paper Ticket themselves*.  The passenger *can print the Itinerary and Receipt*, but not the actual Ticket, if a Ticket even exists since many airlines use Ticketless travel.

Comment: The rule you will fine is most often stated as "Evidence or Proof of Onward Travel" and there are other ways to prove onward travel.  The two, maybe three, times I've been asked this, a printed Itinerary satisfied the Agent/Officer. 

There are several additional reasons:

 1. There are other ways to leave many countries by land, car, sea or rail.
 2. Traditional Paper Tickets are bearer instruments so the physical paper ticket has actual value.  This puts the holder is a risky situation for theft of loss.
 3. A Paper Ticket has no additional information over the Receipt/Itinerary.

Comment: @Johns-305 Ah, sorry for the confusion. I meant a ticket receipt. Edited.

Comment: Them the answer is very simple, because it satisfies various countries "Proof of Onward or Return Travel" requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it still happens sometimes - although not necessarily always at the arrival, sometimes even on departure.

For example, leaving Auckland, New Zealand for Argentina, I had my departure ticket from Argentina stored in my email for x months later when I would need it.  I showed it to the counter, but they actually sent me up to their (Aerolineas Argentinas) office in the airport to print out my (leaving Argentina!) paper ticket as evidence, before they'd let me check-in for the flight *from* New Zealand.

Also be aware that you may not have ready access to the internet on arrival - eg in Cuba or Iran.  Cuba, I was asked for my travel insurance document which was on my phone, they wouldn't accept it, and had no facilities to print it out, so I was forced to purchase their insurance on the spot.  If it was on paper (as another tourist had), it would have been accepted.

It's not necessarily that they're concerned about fraud, sometimes it's just a legacy law - ignore the digital age for the moment and consider the requirement has, in some places, always just been 'you must have written (on paper) evidence of your tickets/paperwork'.  If you don't, and it's a requirement for entry, you may well be sent back home at your cost.

Comment: Are you sure it was a paper ticket and not just a receipt with the itinerary?  They really, really don't want to convert a ticket and a paper ticket doesn't tell you any thing more than a receipt would, especially to check in staff.

Comment: @Johns-305 we may need clarification from you and the OP before I answer - you're differentiating between a paper ticket and a receipt, and he's using "flight ticket receipt on paper".  Long story short, they wanted written, printed evidence of my flight out of Argentina in the first example, and Cuba wanted paper evidence of my insurance, despite having it on my phone.

Comment: The original question included "paper ticket", it's been edited to the more likely question of a printed *receipt*.  Also, you specifically say, perhaps unintentionally, "print out my...paper ticket as evidence".